# SFINAE-ing any container into a c-style array view

Tags: c++, c++14, sfinae, type-traits, array-view

I'm making a simple, non-owning array view class:

```
template <typename T>
class array_view {
    T* data_;
    size_t len_;
    // ...
};
```

I want to construct it from any container that has `data()` and `size()` member functions, but SFINAE-d correctly such that `array_view` is only constructible from some container `C` if it would then be valid and safe behavior to actually traverse `data_`.

I went with:

```
template <typename C,
          typename D = decltype(std::declval<C>().data()),
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_convertible<D, T*>::value &&
              std::is_same<std::remove_cv_t<T>,
                            std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_pointer_t<D>>>::value>
           >
array_view(C&& container)
: data_(container.data()), len_(container.size())
{ }
```

That seems wholly unsatisfying and I'm not even sure it's correct. Am I correctly including all the right containers and excluding all the wrong ones? Is there an easier way to write this requirement?

Comment: @dyp Yeah in retrospect it makes no sense, lemme take it out.

Comment: So what's the relation to the proposed `array_view`? E.g. [N4512](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html) (not sure if that's the current revision). Do you want us to criticize that paper, or compare your approach to theirs?

Comment: @dyp Never heard of that paper, so... I dunno. Whatever you want to answer :)

Comment: @dyp Right, I'm half-broken for `string` (can do `array_view<const char>` at least) and fully broken for `initializer_list`.  Guess the One True Overload idea won't fly.

Comment: Well I'd argue that you're not broken for `string`. If some function defines an interface `void f(array_view<char>)`, you shouldn't be able to use a `string`. Not sure why `initializer_list` has no `.data` member.

Comment: Btw, the Guideline Support Library (Stroustrup & Sutter et al) proposes a mutable `string_view`, so I guess some form of mutable `string::data` will be required as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take a look at the proposed `std::experimental::array_view` in [N4512](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html), we find the following `Viewable` requirement in Table 104:

```
Expression   Return type                    Operational semantics

v.size()    Convertible to ptrdiff_t

v.data()    Type T* such that T* is        static_cast(v.data()) points to a
            implicitly convertible to U*,  contiguous sequence of at least
            and is_same_v<remove_cv_t<T>,  v.size() objects of (possibly
            remove_cv_t<U>> is true.       cv-qualified) type remove_cv_t<U>.
```

That is, the authors are using essentially the same check for `.data()`, but add another one for `.size()`.

In order to use pointer arithmetic on `U` by using operations with `T`, the types need to be *similar* according to [expr.add]p6. *Similarity* is defined for qualification conversions, this is why checking for implicit convertibility and then checking similarity (via the `is_same`) is sufficient for pointer arithmetic.

Of course, there's no guarantee for the operational semantics.

---

In the Standard Library, the only contiguous containers are `std::array` and `std::vector`. There's also `std::basic_string` which has a `.data()` member, but `std::initializer_list` does not, despite it being contiguous.

All of the `.data()` member functions are specified for each individual class, but they all return an actual pointer (no iterator, no proxy).

This means that checking for the existence of `.data()` is currently sufficient for Standard Library containers; you'd want to add a check for convertibility to make `array_view` less greedy (e.g. `array_view<int>` rejecting some `char* data()`).

---

The implementation can of course be moved away from the interface; you could use Concepts, a concepts emulation, or simply `enable_if` with an appropriate type function. E.g.

```
template<typename T, typename As,
         typename size_rt = decltype(std::declval<T>().size())
         typename data_rt = decltype(std::declval<T>().data())>
constexpr bool is_viewable =
    std::is_convertible_v<size_rt, std::ptrdiff_t>
    && std::is_convertible_v<data_rt, T*>
    && std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>, std::remove_cv_t<data_rt>>;

template <typename C,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<is_viewable<C, T>>
         >
array_view(C&& container)
    : data_(container.data()), len_(container.size())
{ }
```

And yes, that doesn't follow the usual technique for a type function, but it is shorter and you get the idea.

Comment: No sure what you expected, Barry. I would have guessed you've found all this info already. But I don't think there's a significantly shorter non-Concept version of the check.

Comment: Yeah I guess I was hoping there was something I was missing. I do like the idea of putting the check in a constexpr function.